# Prevent using class name as constructor in extended classes

Tags: php, constructor

Check out this example:

```
class ParentClass {
    public function __construct() {
        // Does not prevent using 'SomeObject' as constructor
    }
}

class SomeObject extends ParentClass {
    function SomeObject () {
        // Should not use this as constructor
    }
}

$obj = new SomeObject();
```

How can I prevent for each extending class to use the class name as the constructor? I've tried to set an empty `__construct`, but it still calls the SomeObject-Method (what is actually logical).

Is there a way to disable it in the php.ini or in a similar way as I tried above? I googled about 2 hours but I couldn't find anything.

Greets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try making `function SomeObject` private:

```
private function SomeObject()
```

It is weird, though. According to the [documentation](https://www.php.net/__destruct) the old style constructor should not be called at all when your class contains a `__construct` or when it descends from another class that has a `__construct`. So if you are *really* sure this happens, maybe you can file a bug report.

[edit]
As per request, I tested this locally on PHP 5.4.3. I can confirm that the old style constructor is indeed called. To my feeling this contradicts with this statement:

> For backwards compatibility, if PHP 5 cannot find a __construct()
> function for a given class, and the class did not inherit one from a
> parent class, it will search for the old-style constructor function,
> by the name of the class.

In this case, the class does inherit a `__construct()` function, so PHP should not search for the old constructor.

Comment: Hey GolezTrol, thanks for your answer. I tested it locally at my server, and it has the same behaviour as described in my question (so that would mean it's a bug). Do you probably have the chance to test it on a server of you (just to double check it)?

Comment: I tested it, and it seems you are right. The behaviour is as you described and it contradicts the documentation. My only question (though none of my business) would be: why do you want this method anyway?

Comment: Thank you for testing! I'm going to file a bug report on this. Why I'm doing this: I've written a really tiny MVC-framework, which has a `Controller`-class that has child-classes (the controllers). Each function in this controller represents an action. I failed as I tried to call register/index (because the register controller has an register-action). But I know it's not the clean way, I just wanted to do some quick-and-dirty code. ;)

Comment: I just filed a bug-report, and a developer from php answered that it's just a documentation error and the behavior is correct (loading the old-style constructor although a `__construct` exists in the parent class).

Comment: It's not a bug. It's a feature. X-D